# i need that on selection of drop down list value the check box controls should change dynamically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Our team is using SQL server  as back end. On the web page, we have the values in DropdownList which are reflected dynamically on the STREAM column of a table, which contains data for various Streams( arts, commerce, science, so on).This has been done.
 Now on selection of stream in DDL, we need to provide Checkbox option showing the subjects related to the selected stream only. But our entire SUBJECTS are in one COLUMN of another table. How to retrieve only the Related subjects to the stream.

Here is the aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStream" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Branch_Name" DataValueField="Branch_Name" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStream_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkSubjects" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="SUBJECT" DataValueField="SUBJECT">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SUBJECT" HeaderText="SUBJECT" SortExpression="SUBJECT" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ERPConnectionString %>"  SelectCommand="SELECT [Branch_Name] FROM [Branch_Master]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ERPConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [SUBJECT] FROM [Course_Master]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

All Subjects are in one Column and not in separate columns, that's what is causing the problem. Do I need to create multiple columns based on STREAM? Cant this be done by only one common column for all SUBJECTS?
I tried originally CONFIGURE Data Source option on extension of DDL and CheckBox, But it retrieves all data in the column.

Thank you for helping me understand my question better and framing it better. Do you need more input?

Regards,
Santosh

Comment: Probably going to have to include code to get help on this, but I can say with similar problems I've put all the options in the client code and then use javascript to switch around the page dynamically.

Comment: You can hook into the SelectedIndexChanged event to do some server-side processing to get the checkbox values and set them. HOWEVER, this is much nicer / cleaner to do with jquery and ajax all on the client, as @Hogan suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its simple ..

you have to use the selected index changed event of dropdownlist.

- assuming your dropdownlist name is ddlStream
- assuming your checkboxlist name is chkStream
- Set autopostback property of dropdownlist to TRUE.

  ```
   protected void ddlStream_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {          
      SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("connectionString");
      string query = "select [column name] from [table name] where [column name] ="+ddlStream.SelectedItem.Value;

      SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, Con);
      chkStream.DataValueField = "Columnname";
      chkStream.DataTextField = "Columnname";
      conn.Open();
      DataReader reader1 = comm.ExecuteReader();
      chkStream.DataSource = reader1;
      chkStream.DataBind();   
    }
  ```